# Tkinter AutocompleteCombobox automatically sorts dates in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tkinter

I generate a list of business days like so:

```
def bdate():
    bdate = list((pd.bdate_range(start='1/1/2020', end='1/1/2025')))
    for i in bdate:
        index = bdate.index(i)
        bdate[index] = bdate[index].strftime("%d/%m/%y")
    return bdate
```

This creates the following list:

```
['01/01/20', '02/01/20', '03/01/20', '06/01/20', '07/01/20', '08/01/20', '09/01/20', '10/01/20', '13/01/20', '14/01/20', '15/01/20', '16/01/20', '17/01/20', '20/01/20', '21/01/20', '22/01/20', '23/01/20', '24/01/20', '27/01/20', '28/01/20', '29/01/20', '30/01/20', '31/01/20', '03/02/20', '04/02/20', '05/02/20', '06/02/20', '07/02/20', '10/02/20', '11/02/20', '12/02/20', '13/02/20', '14/02/20', '17/02/20', '18/02/20', '19/02/20', '20/02/20', '21/02/20', '24/02/20', '25/02/20', '26/02/20', '27/02/20', '28/02/20', '02/03/20', '03/03/20', '04/03/20', '05/03/20', '06/03/20', '09/03/20', '10/03/20', '11/03/20', '12/03/20', '13/03/20', '16/03/20', '17/03/20', '18/03/20', '19/03/20', '20/03/20', '23/03/20', '24/03/20', '25/03/20', '26/03/20', '27/03/20', '30/03/20', '31/03/20', '01/04/20', '02/04/20', '03/04/20', '06/04/20', '07/04/20', '08/04/20', '09/04/20', '10/04/20', '13/04/20', '14/04/20', '15/04/20', '16/04/20', '17/04/20', '20/04/20', '21/04/20', '22/04/20', '23/04/20', '24/04/20', '27/04/20', '28/04/20', '29/04/20', '30/04/20', '01/05/20', '04/05/20', '05/05/20', '06/05/20', '07/05/20', '08/05/20', '11/05/20', '12/05/20', '13/05/20', '14/05/20', '15/05/20', '18/05/20', '19/05/20', '20/05/20', '21/05/20', '22/05/20', '25/05/20', '26/05/20', '27/05/20', '28/05/20', '29/05/20', '01/06/20', '02/06/20', '03/06/20', '04/06/20', '05/06/20', '08/06/20', '09/06/20', '10/06/20', '11/06/20', '12/06/20', '15/06/20', '16/06/20', '17/06/20', '18/06/20', '19/06/20', '22/06/20', '23/06/20', '24/06/20', '25/06/20', '26/06/20', '29/06/20', '30/06/20', '01/07/20', '02/07/20', '03/07/20', '06/07/20', '07/07/20', '08/07/20', '09/07/20', '10/07/20', '13/07/20', '14/07/20', '15/07/20', '16/07/20', '17/07/20', '20/07/20', '21/07/20', '22/07/20', '23/07/20', '24/07/20', '27/07/20', '28/07/20', '29/07/20', '30/07/20', '31/07/20', '03/08/20', '04/08/20', '05/08/20', '06/08/20', '07/08/20', '10/08/20', '11/08/20', '12/08/20', '13/08/20', '14/08/20', '17/08/20', '18/08/20', '19/08/20', '20/08/20', '21/08/20', '24/08/20', '25/08/20', '26/08/20', '27/08/20', '28/08/20', '31/08/20', '01/09/20', '02/09/20', '03/09/20', '04/09/20', '07/09/20', '08/09/20', '09/09/20', '10/09/20', '11/09/20', '14/09/20', '15/09/20', '16/09/20', '17/09/20', '18/09/20', '21/09/20', '22/09/20', '23/09/20', '24/09/20', '25/09/20', '28/09/20', '29/09/20', '30/09/20', '01/10/20', '02/10/20', '05/10/20', '06/10/20', '07/10/20', '08/10/20', '09/10/20', '12/10/20', '13/10/20', '14/10/20', '15/10/20', '16/10/20', '19/10/20', '20/10/20', '21/10/20', '22/10/20', '23/10/20', '26/10/20', '27/10/20', '28/10/20', '29/10/20', '30/10/20', '02/11/20', '03/11/20', '04/11/20', '05/11/20', '06/11/20', '09/11/20', '10/11/20', '11/11/20', '12/11/20', '13/11/20', '16/11/20', '17/11/20', '18/11/20', '19/11/20', '20/11/20', '23/11/20', '24/11/20', '25/11/20', '26/11/20', '27/11/20', '30/11/20', '01/12/20', '02/12/20', '03/12/20', '04/12/20', '07/12/20', '08/12/20', '09/12/20', '10/12/20', '11/12/20', '14/12/20', '15/12/20', '16/12/20', '17/12/20', '18/12/20', '21/12/20', '22/12/20', '23/12/20', '24/12/20', '25/12/20', '28/12/20', '29/12/20', '30/12/20', '31/12/20', '01/01/21', '04/01/21', '05/01/21', '06/01/21', '07/01/21', '08/01/21', '11/01/21', '12/01/21', '13/01/21', '14/01/21', '15/01/21', '18/01/21', '19/01/21', '20/01/21', '21/01/21', '22/01/21', '25/01/21', '26/01/21', '27/01/21', '28/01/21', '29/01/21', '01/02/21', '02/02/21', '03/02/21', '04/02/21', '05/02/21', '08/02/21', '09/02/21', '10/02/21', '11/02/21', '12/02/21', '15/02/21', '16/02/21', '17/02/21', '18/02/21', '19/02/21', '22/02/21', '23/02/21', '24/02/21', '25/02/21', '26/02/21', '01/03/21', '02/03/21', '03/03/21', '04/03/21', '05/03/21', '08/03/21', '09/03/21', '10/03/21', '11/03/21', '12/03/21', '15/03/21', '16/03/21', '17/03/21', '18/03/21', '19/03/21', '22/03/21', '23/03/21', '24/03/21', '25/03/21', '26/03/21', '29/03/21', '30/03/21', '31/03/21', '01/04/21', '02/04/21', '05/04/21', '06/04/21', '07/04/21', '08/04/21', '09/04/21', '12/04/21', '13/04/21', '14/04/21', '15/04/21', '16/04/21', '19/04/21', '20/04/21', '21/04/21', '22/04/21', '23/04/21', '26/04/21', '27/04/21', '28/04/21', '29/04/21', '30/04/21', '03/05/21', '04/05/21', '05/05/21', '06/05/21', '07/05/21', '10/05/21', '11/05/21', '12/05/21', '13/05/21', '14/05/21', '17/05/21', '18/05/21', '19/05/21', '20/05/21', '21/05/21', '24/05/21', '25/05/21', '26/05/21', '27/05/21', '28/05/21', '31/05/21', '01/06/21', '02/06/21', '03/06/21', '04/06/21', '07/06/21', '08/06/21', '09/06/21', '10/06/21', '11/06/21', '14/06/21', '15/06/21', '16/06/21', '17/06/21', '18/06/21', '21/06/21', '22/06/21', '23/06/21', '24/06/21', '25/06/21', '28/06/21', '29/06/21', '30/06/21', '01/07/21', '02/07/21', '05/07/21', '06/07/21', '07/07/21', '08/07/21', '09/07/21', '12/07/21', '13/07/21', '14/07/21', '15/07/21', '16/07/21', '19/07/21', '20/07/21', '21/07/21', '22/07/21', '23/07/21', '26/07/21', '27/07/21', '28/07/21', '29/07/21', '30/07/21', '02/08/21', '03/08/21', '04/08/21', '05/08/21', '06/08/21', '09/08/21', '10/08/21', '11/08/21', '12/08/21', '13/08/21', '16/08/21', '17/08/21', '18/08/21', '19/08/21', '20/08/21', '23/08/21', '24/08/21', '25/08/21', '26/08/21', '27/08/21', '30/08/21', '31/08/21', '01/09/21', '02/09/21', '03/09/21', '06/09/21', '07/09/21', '08/09/21', '09/09/21', '10/09/21', '13/09/21', '14/09/21', '15/09/21', '16/09/21', '17/09/21', '20/09/21', '21/09/21', '22/09/21', '23/09/21', '24/09/21', '27/09/21', '28/09/21', '29/09/21', '30/09/21', '01/10/21', '04/10/21', '05/10/21', '06/10/21', '07/10/21', '08/10/21', '11/10/21', '12/10/21', '13/10/21', '14/10/21', '15/10/21', '18/10/21', '19/10/21', '20/10/21', '21/10/21', '22/10/21', '25/10/21', '26/10/21', '27/10/21', '28/10/21', '29/10/21', '01/11/21', '02/11/21', '03/11/21', '04/11/21', '05/11/21', '08/11/21', '09/11/21', '10/11/21', '11/11/21', '12/11/21', '15/11/21', '16/11/21', '17/11/21', '18/11/21', '19/11/21', '22/11/21', '23/11/21', '24/11/21', '25/11/21', '26/11/21', '29/11/21', '30/11/21', '01/12/21', '02/12/21', '03/12/21', '06/12/21', '07/12/21', '08/12/21', '09/12/21', '10/12/21', '13/12/21', '14/12/21', '15/12/21', '16/12/21', '17/12/21', '20/12/21', '21/12/21', '22/12/21', '23/12/21', '24/12/21', '27/12/21', '28/12/21', '29/12/21', '30/12/21', '31/12/21', '03/01/22', '04/01/22', '05/01/22', '06/01/22', '07/01/22', '10/01/22', '11/01/22', '12/01/22', '13/01/22', '14/01/22', '17/01/22', '18/01/22', '19/01/22', '20/01/22', '21/01/22', '24/01/22', '25/01/22', '26/01/22', '27/01/22', '28/01/22', '31/01/22', '01/02/22', '02/02/22', '03/02/22', '04/02/22', '07/02/22', '08/02/22', '09/02/22', '10/02/22', '11/02/22', '14/02/22', '15/02/22', '16/02/22', '17/02/22', '18/02/22', '21/02/22', '22/02/22', '23/02/22', '24/02/22', '25/02/22', '28/02/22', '01/03/22', '02/03/22', '03/03/22', '04/03/22', '07/03/22', '08/03/22', '09/03/22', '10/03/22', '11/03/22', '14/03/22', '15/03/22', '16/03/22', '17/03/22', '18/03/22', '21/03/22', '22/03/22', '23/03/22', '24/03/22', '25/03/22', '28/03/22', '29/03/22', '30/03/22', '31/03/22', '01/04/22', '04/04/22', '05/04/22', '06/04/22', '07/04/22', '08/04/22', '11/04/22', '12/04/22', '13/04/22', '14/04/22', '15/04/22', '18/04/22', '19/04/22', '20/04/22', '21/04/22', '22/04/22', '25/04/22', '26/04/22', '27/04/22', '28/04/22', '29/04/22', '02/05/22', '03/05/22', '04/05/22', '05/05/22', '06/05/22', '09/05/22', '10/05/22', '11/05/22', '12/05/22', '13/05/22', '16/05/22', '17/05/22', '18/05/22', '19/05/22', '20/05/22', '23/05/22', '24/05/22', '25/05/22', '26/05/22', '27/05/22', '30/05/22', '31/05/22', '01/06/22', '02/06/22', '03/06/22', '06/06/22', '07/06/22', '08/06/22', '09/06/22', '10/06/22', '13/06/22', '14/06/22', '15/06/22', '16/06/22', '17/06/22', '20/06/22', '21/06/22', '22/06/22', '23/06/22', '24/06/22', '27/06/22', '28/06/22', '29/06/22', '30/06/22', '01/07/22', '04/07/22', '05/07/22', '06/07/22', '07/07/22', '08/07/22', '11/07/22', '12/07/22', '13/07/22', '14/07/22', '15/07/22', '18/07/22', '19/07/22', '20/07/22', '21/07/22', '22/07/22', '25/07/22', '26/07/22', '27/07/22', '28/07/22', '29/07/22', '01/08/22', '02/08/22', '03/08/22', '04/08/22', '05/08/22', '08/08/22', '09/08/22', '10/08/22', '11/08/22', '12/08/22', '15/08/22', '16/08/22', '17/08/22', '18/08/22', '19/08/22', '22/08/22', '23/08/22', '24/08/22', '25/08/22', '26/08/22', '29/08/22', '30/08/22', '31/08/22', '01/09/22', '02/09/22', '05/09/22', '06/09/22', '07/09/22', '08/09/22', '09/09/22', '12/09/22', '13/09/22', '14/09/22', '15/09/22', '16/09/22', '19/09/22', '20/09/22', '21/09/22', '22/09/22', '23/09/22', '26/09/22', '27/09/22', '28/09/22', '29/09/22', '30/09/22', '03/10/22', '04/10/22', '05/10/22', '06/10/22', '07/10/22', '10/10/22', '11/10/22', '12/10/22', '13/10/22', '14/10/22', '17/10/22', '18/10/22', '19/10/22', '20/10/22', '21/10/22', '24/10/22', '25/10/22', '26/10/22', '27/10/22', '28/10/22', '31/10/22', '01/11/22', '02/11/22', '03/11/22', '04/11/22', '07/11/22', '08/11/22', '09/11/22', '10/11/22', '11/11/22', '14/11/22', '15/11/22', '16/11/22', '17/11/22', '18/11/22', '21/11/22', '22/11/22', '23/11/22', '24/11/22', '25/11/22', '28/11/22', '29/11/22', '30/11/22', '01/12/22', '02/12/22', '05/12/22', '06/12/22', '07/12/22', '08/12/22', '09/12/22', '12/12/22', '13/12/22', '14/12/22', '15/12/22', '16/12/22', '19/12/22', '20/12/22', '21/12/22', '22/12/22', '23/12/22', '26/12/22', '27/12/22', '28/12/22', '29/12/22', '30/12/22', '02/01/23', '03/01/23', '04/01/23', '05/01/23', '06/01/23', '09/01/23', '10/01/23', '11/01/23', '12/01/23', '13/01/23', '16/01/23', '17/01/23', '18/01/23', '19/01/23', '20/01/23', '23/01/23', '24/01/23', '25/01/23', '26/01/23', '27/01/23', '30/01/23', '31/01/23', '01/02/23', '02/02/23', '03/02/23', '06/02/23', '07/02/23', '08/02/23', '09/02/23', '10/02/23', '13/02/23', '14/02/23', '15/02/23', '16/02/23', '17/02/23', '20/02/23', '21/02/23', '22/02/23', '23/02/23', '24/02/23', '27/02/23', '28/02/23', '01/03/23', '02/03/23', '03/03/23', '06/03/23', '07/03/23', '08/03/23', '09/03/23', '10/03/23', '13/03/23', '14/03/23', '15/03/23', '16/03/23', '17/03/23', '20/03/23', '21/03/23', '22/03/23', '23/03/23', '24/03/23', '27/03/23', '28/03/23', '29/03/23', '30/03/23', '31/03/23', '03/04/23', '04/04/23', '05/04/23', '06/04/23', '07/04/23', '10/04/23', '11/04/23', '12/04/23', '13/04/23', '14/04/23', '17/04/23', '18/04/23', '19/04/23', '20/04/23', '21/04/23', '24/04/23', '25/04/23', '26/04/23', '27/04/23', '28/04/23', '01/05/23', '02/05/23', '03/05/23', '04/05/23', '05/05/23', '08/05/23', '09/05/23', '10/05/23', '11/05/23', '12/05/23', '15/05/23', '16/05/23', '17/05/23', '18/05/23', '19/05/23', '22/05/23', '23/05/23', '24/05/23', '25/05/23', '26/05/23', '29/05/23', '30/05/23', '31/05/23', '01/06/23', '02/06/23', '05/06/23', '06/06/23', '07/06/23', '08/06/23', '09/06/23', '12/06/23', '13/06/23', '14/06/23', '15/06/23', '16/06/23', '19/06/23', '20/06/23', '21/06/23', '22/06/23', '23/06/23', '26/06/23', '27/06/23', '28/06/23', '29/06/23', '30/06/23', '03/07/23', '04/07/23', '05/07/23', '06/07/23', '07/07/23', '10/07/23', '11/07/23', '12/07/23', '13/07/23', '14/07/23', '17/07/23', '18/07/23', '19/07/23', '20/07/23', '21/07/23', '24/07/23', '25/07/23', '26/07/23', '27/07/23', '28/07/23', '31/07/23', '01/08/23', '02/08/23', '03/08/23', '04/08/23', '07/08/23', '08/08/23', '09/08/23', '10/08/23', '11/08/23', '14/08/23', '15/08/23', '16/08/23', '17/08/23', '18/08/23', '21/08/23', '22/08/23', '23/08/23', '24/08/23', '25/08/23', '28/08/23', '29/08/23', '30/08/23', '31/08/23', '01/09/23', '04/09/23', '05/09/23', '06/09/23', '07/09/23', '08/09/23', '11/09/23', '12/09/23', '13/09/23', '14/09/23', '15/09/23', '18/09/23', '19/09/23', '20/09/23', '21/09/23', '22/09/23', '25/09/23', '26/09/23', '27/09/23', '28/09/23', '29/09/23', '02/10/23', '03/10/23', '04/10/23', '05/10/23', '06/10/23', '09/10/23', '10/10/23', '11/10/23', '12/10/23', '13/10/23', '16/10/23', '17/10/23', '18/10/23', '19/10/23', '20/10/23', '23/10/23', '24/10/23', '25/10/23', '26/10/23', '27/10/23', '30/10/23', '31/10/23', '01/11/23', '02/11/23', '03/11/23', '06/11/23', '07/11/23', '08/11/23', '09/11/23', '10/11/23', '13/11/23', '14/11/23', '15/11/23', '16/11/23', '17/11/23', '20/11/23', '21/11/23', '22/11/23', '23/11/23', '24/11/23', '27/11/23', '28/11/23', '29/11/23', '30/11/23', '01/12/23', '04/12/23', '05/12/23', '06/12/23', '07/12/23', '08/12/23', '11/12/23', '12/12/23', '13/12/23', '14/12/23', '15/12/23', '18/12/23', '19/12/23', '20/12/23', '21/12/23', '22/12/23', '25/12/23', '26/12/23', '27/12/23', '28/12/23', '29/12/23', '01/01/24', '02/01/24', '03/01/24', '04/01/24', '05/01/24', '08/01/24', '09/01/24', '10/01/24', '11/01/24', '12/01/24', '15/01/24', '16/01/24', '17/01/24', '18/01/24', '19/01/24', '22/01/24', '23/01/24', '24/01/24', '25/01/24', '26/01/24', '29/01/24', '30/01/24', '31/01/24', '01/02/24', '02/02/24', '05/02/24', '06/02/24', '07/02/24', '08/02/24', '09/02/24', '12/02/24', '13/02/24', '14/02/24', '15/02/24', '16/02/24', '19/02/24', '20/02/24', '21/02/24', '22/02/24', '23/02/24', '26/02/24', '27/02/24', '28/02/24', '29/02/24', '01/03/24', '04/03/24', '05/03/24', '06/03/24', '07/03/24', '08/03/24', '11/03/24', '12/03/24', '13/03/24', '14/03/24', '15/03/24', '18/03/24', '19/03/24', '20/03/24', '21/03/24', '22/03/24', '25/03/24', '26/03/24', '27/03/24', '28/03/24', '29/03/24', '01/04/24', '02/04/24', '03/04/24', '04/04/24', '05/04/24', '08/04/24', '09/04/24', '10/04/24', '11/04/24', '12/04/24', '15/04/24', '16/04/24', '17/04/24', '18/04/24', '19/04/24', '22/04/24', '23/04/24', '24/04/24', '25/04/24', '26/04/24', '29/04/24', '30/04/24', '01/05/24', '02/05/24', '03/05/24', '06/05/24', '07/05/24', '08/05/24', '09/05/24', '10/05/24', '13/05/24', '14/05/24', '15/05/24', '16/05/24', '17/05/24', '20/05/24', '21/05/24', '22/05/24', '23/05/24', '24/05/24', '27/05/24', '28/05/24', '29/05/24', '30/05/24', '31/05/24', '03/06/24', '04/06/24', '05/06/24', '06/06/24', '07/06/24', '10/06/24', '11/06/24', '12/06/24', '13/06/24', '14/06/24', '17/06/24', '18/06/24', '19/06/24', '20/06/24', '21/06/24', '24/06/24', '25/06/24', '26/06/24', '27/06/24', '28/06/24', '01/07/24', '02/07/24', '03/07/24', '04/07/24', '05/07/24', '08/07/24', '09/07/24', '10/07/24', '11/07/24', '12/07/24', '15/07/24', '16/07/24', '17/07/24', '18/07/24', '19/07/24', '22/07/24', '23/07/24', '24/07/24', '25/07/24', '26/07/24', '29/07/24', '30/07/24', '31/07/24', '01/08/24', '02/08/24', '05/08/24', '06/08/24', '07/08/24', '08/08/24', '09/08/24', '12/08/24', '13/08/24', '14/08/24', '15/08/24', '16/08/24', '19/08/24', '20/08/24', '21/08/24', '22/08/24', '23/08/24', '26/08/24', '27/08/24', '28/08/24', '29/08/24', '30/08/24', '02/09/24', '03/09/24', '04/09/24', '05/09/24', '06/09/24', '09/09/24', '10/09/24', '11/09/24', '12/09/24', '13/09/24', '16/09/24', '17/09/24', '18/09/24', '19/09/24', '20/09/24', '23/09/24', '24/09/24', '25/09/24', '26/09/24', '27/09/24', '30/09/24', '01/10/24', '02/10/24', '03/10/24', '04/10/24', '07/10/24', '08/10/24', '09/10/24', '10/10/24', '11/10/24', '14/10/24', '15/10/24', '16/10/24', '17/10/24', '18/10/24', '21/10/24', '22/10/24', '23/10/24', '24/10/24', '25/10/24', '28/10/24', '29/10/24', '30/10/24', '31/10/24', '01/11/24', '04/11/24', '05/11/24', '06/11/24', '07/11/24', '08/11/24', '11/11/24', '12/11/24', '13/11/24', '14/11/24', '15/11/24', '18/11/24', '19/11/24', '20/11/24', '21/11/24', '22/11/24', '25/11/24', '26/11/24', '27/11/24', '28/11/24', '29/11/24', '02/12/24', '03/12/24', '04/12/24', '05/12/24', '06/12/24', '09/12/24', '10/12/24', '11/12/24', '12/12/24', '13/12/24', '16/12/24', '17/12/24', '18/12/24', '19/12/24', '20/12/24', '23/12/24', '24/12/24', '25/12/24', '26/12/24', '27/12/24', '30/12/24', '31/12/24', '01/01/25']
```

However when I pass this onto my combolist like so:

```
deliverydate_box = AutocompleteCombobox(root, width=20, completevalues=bdate_list)
deliverydate_box.place(x=100,y=230,width=200,height=25)
```

I am given the following result:

[image]

What I want is the dates in the combolist displayed in the same order as the original list, eg, like a normal calendar.

What solutions exist?

I have included a full example of my code, in order for the scenario to be replicated.

```
from ttkwidgets.autocomplete import AutocompleteCombobox
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

def ask_confirm():
    confirm = messagebox.askquestion('Warning', 'Are you sure you want to send this ticket?')
    if confirm == "yes":
        global data_container
        data_container = [buyer_box.get(), seller_box.get(), metal_box.get(), tonnage_box.get(), 
                          deliverydate_box.get(), price_box.get(), premium_box.get(), pricingdate_box.get(),
                          location_box.get(), deliveryterms_box.get()]
        print(data_container)


def bdate():
    bdate = list((pd.bdate_range(start='1/1/2020', end='1/1/2025')))
    for i in bdate:
        index = bdate.index(i)
        bdate[index] = bdate[index].strftime("%d/%m/%y")
    return bdate

bdate_list = bdate()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Physical Deal Porter")
width=400
height=500
screenwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screenheight = root.winfo_screenheight()
alignstr = '%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, (screenwidth - width) / 2, (screenheight - height) / 2)
root.geometry(alignstr)
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)


HELLO = tk.Label(root, text = " HELLO ", background = '#3b5997', foreground ="white", font = ("Times New Roman", 25))
HELLO.place(x=100,y=20,width=200,height=50)

buyer = tk.Label(root, text="Buyer :")
buyer.place(x=10,y=90,width=70,height=25)
buyer_box = AutocompleteCombobox(root, width=20, completevalues=bdate_list)
buyer_box.place(x=100,y=90,width=200,height=25)

seller = tk.Label(root, text="Seller :")
seller.place(x=10,y=125,width=70,height=25)
seller_box = AutocompleteCombobox(root, width=20, completevalues=bdate_list)
seller_box.place(x=100,y=125,width=200,height=25)

metal = tk.Label(root, text="Commodity :")
metal.place(x=10,y=160,width=70,height=25)
metal_box = AutocompleteCombobox(root, width=20, completevalues=bdate_list)
metal_box.place(x=100,y=160,width=200,height=25)

tonnage = tk.Label(root, text="Tonnage :")
tonnage.place(x=10,y=195,width=70,height=25)
tonnage_note = tk.Label(root, text="(MT)")
tonnage_note.place(x=290,y=195,width=70,height=25)
tonnage_box = tk.Entry(root, width=20)
tonnage_box.place(x=100,y=195,width=200,height=25)

deliverydate = tk.Label(root, text="Delivery :")
deliverydate.place(x=10,y=230,width=70,height=25)
deliverydate_box = AutocompleteCombobox(root, width=20, completevalues=bdate_list)
deliverydate_box.place(x=100,y=230,width=200,height=25)

price = tk.Label(root, text="Price :")
price.place(x=10,y=265,width=70,height=25)
price_note = tk.Label(root, text="(USD)")
price_note.place(x=290,y=265,width=70,height=25)
price_box = tk.Entry(root, width=20)
price_box.place(x=100,y=265,width=200,height=25)

premium = tk.Label(root, text="Premium :")
premium.place(x=10,y=300,width=70,height=25)
premium_note = tk.Label(root, text="(USD)")
premium_note.place(x=290,y=300,width=70,height=25)
premium_box = tk.Entry(root, width=20)
premium_box.place(x=100,y=300,width=200,height=25)

pricingdate = tk.Label(root, text="Pricing :")
pricingdate.place(x=10,y=335,width=70,height=25)
pricingdate_box = AutocompleteCombobox(root, width=20, completevalues=bdate_list)
pricingdate_box.place(x=100,y=335,width=200,height=25)

location = tk.Label(root, text="Location :")
location.place(x=10,y=370,width=70,height=25)
location_box = AutocompleteCombobox(root, width=20, completevalues=bdate_list)
location_box.place(x=100,y=370,width=200,height=25)

deliveryterms = tk.Label(root, text="Terms :")
deliveryterms.place(x=10,y=405,width=70,height=25)
deliveryterms_box = AutocompleteCombobox(root, width=20, completevalues=bdate_list)
deliveryterms_box.place(x=100,y=405,width=200,height=25)

send = tk.Button(root, text = " Send ", background = '#3b5997', foreground ="white", font = ("Times New Roman", 16), command = ask_confirm)
send.place(x=150,y=450,width=100,height=30)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please include a [mre]

Comment: Its generally a bad idea to edit a list in place while looping over it. You should loop over the original range, appending the date string to an empty list (i.e. for x in pd.bdate_range).

Comment: @Sujay This has been done. Hopefully this helps you, help me

Comment: @Alan I can see why if you're jumping around the list but considering im just crawling through it, element by element, there is no possibility of issues correct?

Comment: @GeorgeBoast Incorrect. Behaviour is not guaranteed. It is unlikely to cause a problem if you are not changing the number of elements, however, you don't know if behind the scenes the python vm has to make adjustments. It is recommended you do not change a list during iteration unless you have no choice. And here you have much better choices.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: The sort appears to be an undocumented "feature" of the AutocompleteCombobox. It does not happen if you use the regular Combobox.

At the bottom is the minimal reproducible example. Here is an explanation that shows the difference between the behaviour of the two Comboboxes:

```
# AutocompleteCombobox is in ttkwidgets
from ttkwidgets.autocomplete import AutocompleteCombobox
# Regular Combobox is in ttk
from tkinter import ttk
```

Use a list comprehension to generate the dates from the range. Learn list, dict and set comprehensions, they are amazing:

```
bdate_list = [ xdate.strftime("%d/%m/%y") for xdate in \
                 pd.bdate_range(start='1/1/2020', end='1/1/2025') ]
```

```
# Note the only difference between the two is that the regular
# Combobox uses values
deliverydate_box = ttk.Combobox(root, width=20, values=bdate_list)
# AutocompleteCombobox uses completevalues
pricingdate_box = AutocompleteCombobox(root, width=20, completevalues=bdate_list)
```

Interestingly, according to an error message I got while testing, `completevalues` maps onto `values`. I would guess this has a different name because it applies the sort before passing the values off to the combobox, unlike the regular which accepts the raw values as expected.

Looking at the code from [the author's mailing list post](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2012-January/003041.html), the relevant line is:

```
def set_completion_list(self, completion_list):
    """Use our completion list as our drop down selection menu, arrows move through menu."""
    self._completion_list = sorted(completion_list, key=str.lower) # Work with a sorted list
```

This means the behaviour is explicit. To overcome it, if you really want to use AutoComplete over a regular Combobox, you would have to use the International Date Format:

```
bdate_list = [ xdate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for xdate in \
                 pd.bdate_range(start='1/1/2020', end='1/1/2025') ]
```

Full working code here:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

from tkinter import messagebox
from ttkwidgets.autocomplete import AutocompleteCombobox
from tkinter import ttk

bdate_list = [ xdate.strftime("%d/%m/%y") for xdate in \
                 pd.bdate_range(start='1/1/2020', end='1/1/2025') ]

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Physical Deal Porter")
width=400
height=500
screenwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screenheight = root.winfo_screenheight()
alignstr = '%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, (screenwidth - width) / 2, (screenheight - height) / 2)
root.geometry(alignstr)
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

deliverydate = tk.Label(root, text="Delivery :")
deliverydate.place(x=10,y=230,width=70,height=25)
deliverydate_box = ttk.Combobox(root, width=20, values=bdate_list)
deliverydate_box.place(x=100,y=230,width=200,height=25)

pricingdate = tk.Label(root, text="Pricing :")
pricingdate.place(x=10,y=335,width=70,height=25)
pricingdate_box = AutocompleteCombobox(root, width=20, completevalues=bdate_list)
pricingdate_box.place(x=100,y=335,width=200,height=25)

root.mainloop()
```

Otherwise, pretty good. Well done!